# Change Jquery animimation dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change [kernburns slideshow](https://github.com/toymakerlabs/kenburns) after the page loading, for example after pressing a button.

This is the code of http://jsfiddle.net/s4C5K/1/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="kenburns-slideshow"></div>
<div id="kenburns-description">
    <h1 id="status">Loading Images..</h1>
    <h1 id="slide-title"></h1>
    <h1 class="title"><a href="http://www.github.com/toymakerlabs/kenburns/" target="blank">Kenburns.js
    </a></h1>
    <p>Kenburns.js is a lightweight and flexible Jquery gallery plugin that loads images and features an animated, pan-and-zoom, Ken Burns style effect. Grab the source from my <a href="http://www.github.com/toymakerlabs/kenburns/" target="blank"> Github</a></p>
</div>
<button onclick="slidechange()">New slide</button>
```

**JS CODE:**

the code simply initiate the slideshow. The function `slidechange()` empties the div and change the **"images"** variable and redo the operations:

```
var titles = ["Epic Day at Refugio",
          "Colors of Spring",
          "First Flowers",
          "Magic Hour at Sands Beach",
          "Coal Oil Point",
          "Hope Ranch Views"];

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#kenburns-slideshow').Kenburns({
    images: [
                    "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image0.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image1.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image2.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image3.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image4.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image5.jpg"            ],
        scale:0.75,
        duration:8000,
        fadeSpeed:1200,
        ease3d:'cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.050, 0.550, 0.950)',

        onSlideComplete: function(){
            $('#slide-title').html(titles[this.getSlideIndex()]);
        },
        onLoadingComplete: function(){
            $('#status').html("Loading Complete");
        }

    });
});

    function slidechange() {
    $('#kenburns-slideshow').empty();    
    $('#kenburns-slideshow').Kenburns({
        images: [
                    "http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070903093660/nonciclopedia/images/thumb/c/cf/Fini.jpg/200px-Fini.jpg",
            "http://www.caffettieragiornaliera.it/wp-content/gallery/signor-boh/boh-facebook.gif",
            "http://www.lanostratv.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/rai-boh-flop-facchinetti.jpg",
                    ],
        scale:0.75,
        duration:8000,
        fadeSpeed:1200,
        ease3d:'cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.050, 0.550, 0.950)',

        onSlideComplete: function(){
            $('#slide-title').html(titles[this.getSlideIndex()]);
        },
        onLoadingComplete: function(){
            $('#status').html("Loading Complete");
        }

    });
    };
```

---

*It does not work without errors.*

Comment: What are the errors you are having?

Comment: no errors, only the div empty after pressing the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="kenburns-slideshow"><div id='foo'></div></div>
```

Inserted new div inside. Leaving his parent as placeholder.
Then on button click
Completley remove old div.

```
$('#foo').remove();
```

Then create same element and attach Kenburns library to it.

```
$("<div></div>").attr("id","foo").appendTo("#kenburns-slideshow").Kenburns({});
```

(with your settings in example)

Comment: Good solution, but why does it needed a new div and does not work if the div revert to the original state?

Answer (score 1):

As Marius wrote:

```
var titles = ["Epic Day at Refugio",
          "Colors of Spring",
          "First Flowers",
          "Magic Hour at Sands Beach",
          "Coal Oil Point",
          "Hope Ranch Views"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("<div></div>").attr("id","newdiv").appendTo("#kenburns-slideshow").Kenburns({
        images: [
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image0.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image1.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image2.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image3.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image4.jpg",
            "http://www.toymakerlabs.com/kenburns/images/image5.jpg"            ],
        scale:0.75,
        duration:8000,
        fadeSpeed:1200,
        ease3d:'cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.050, 0.550, 0.950)',

        onSlideComplete: function(){
            $('#slide-title').html(titles[this.getSlideIndex()]);
        },
        onLoadingComplete: function(){
            $('#status').html("Loading Complete");
        }

    });
 $('#mybutton').click(slidechange);
    function slidechange() {
    $('#kenburns-slideshow #newdiv').remove();
    $("<div></div>").attr("id","newdiv").appendTo("#kenburns-slideshow").Kenburns({
        images: [
                    "http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070903093660/nonciclopedia/images/thumb/c/cf/Fini.jpg/200px-Fini.jpg",
            "http://www.caffettieragiornaliera.it/wp-content/gallery/signor-boh/boh-facebook.gif",
            "http://www.lanostratv.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/rai-boh-flop-facchinetti.jpg",
                    ],
        scale:0.75,
        duration:8000,
        fadeSpeed:1200,
        ease3d:'cubic-bezier(0.445, 0.050, 0.550, 0.950)',

        onSlideComplete: function(){
            $('#slide-title').html(titles[this.getSlideIndex()]);
        },
        onLoadingComplete: function(){
            $('#status').html("Loading Complete");
        }

    });
    };

});
```

See the above solution at: http://jsfiddle.net/s4C5K/3/